# mustateAsync onSuccess does not exist on type (typescript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-query

I have 2 mutations which are working successfully. However, when I try to add onSuccess and invalidateQueries. I get the following error:

```
Property 'mutateAsync' does not exist on type '{ onSuccess: () => void; }
```

hooks

```
export const useAddUserContact = () => {

    const queryClient = useQueryClient();

    return useMutation(
        (user: any) => axios.post("http://localhost:4000/userContacts", user)
            .then(response => response.data)
    ),
    {
        onSuccess: () => {
            queryClient.invalidateQueries([userContacts.fetchUserContacts])
        }
    }
};

export const useDeleteUserContact = () => {

    const queryClient = useQueryClient();

    return useMutation(
        (userId: string) => axios.delete(`http://localhost:4000/userContacts/${userId}`)
            .then(response => response.data)
    ),
    {
        onSuccess: () => {
            queryClient.invalidateQueries([userContacts.fetchUserContacts])
        }
    }
};
```

use of hooks

```
   const {
        mutateAsync: addUserContactMutation
    } = useAddUserContact();

    const addContactOnClickHandler = (contact: User) => {
        addUserContactMutation(contact);
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

I closed the useMutation call too early, so  accidentally using the comma operator and just returning that config object.